# Gets stats of employee and manager from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like as follows:

```
create table tblEmp(emp varchar(10), issue_no number, mgr varchar(10));

insert into tblEmp(emp, issue_no, mgr) values('abc',123, 'xyz');
insert into tblEmp(emp, issue_no, mgr) values('ijk',222, 'xyz');
insert into tblEmp(emp, issue_no, mgr) values('abc',333, 'xyz');
insert into tblEmp(emp, issue_no, mgr) values('abc',444, 'xyz');
insert into tblEmp(emp, issue_no, mgr) values('kkk',555, 'lll');
insert into tblEmp(emp, issue_no, mgr) values('kkk',555, 'lll');
```

Now I need a query which will return first manager row and count of issues under him/reportees and in later rows employee and count of their issues.

Output should be like

```
user  issue_count
-----------------
xyz       4
  abc     3
  ijk     1
lll       2
  kkk     2
```

Order of employee which don't have any reportees can be in any order.

Comment: You need two queries effectively, one that gets distinct values for manager and the count for them, and then do a UNION to add the second query which is a select distinct user and the count for each user.

Comment: @TineO One hierarchical query will do it for any depth of hierarchy of reportees.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`. The tricky part is to order the records properly; you can set some flags in the `UNION`ed query to be able to properly order the records in the outer query:

```
select usr, cnt from (
    select mgr usr, mgr, 1 pos, count(*) cnt from tblEmp group by mgr
    union all 
    select emp, mgr, 2, count(*) from tblEmp group by emp, mgr
)
order by mgr, pos, usr
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c3e322cb37f371a42b8ffb6d225ab78)**:

```
USR | CNT
:-- | --:
lll |   2
kkk |   2
xyz |   4
abc |   3
ijk |   1
```

Comment: Output is not as expected. query should order reportees after their manager. 

abc and ijk has manager xyz so they should be shown after xyz and kkk should come after lll.

Comment: @nam: well, that's exactly the order than you can see in the result that I am showing: `abc` and `ijk` come after `xyz`, and `kkk`comes after `lll`

Comment: Thanks, could you help me with query if emp and manager details are in different table. in above query only emp and issue_counts are there and there is another table called emp_details having (emp, mgr).
Could you please let me know how we can get above output in that case. That is the actuall requirement.

Comment: This will only work if the hierarchy is always 1 or 2 levels deep. If you have a row `insert into tblEmp(emp, issue_no, mgr) values('jjj',666, 'kkk');` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=61461612008c5d83498e1ddd1fef1959) then there will be duplicate rows where a person is both an employee and manager, the top-level manager would have an incorrect count and the rows won't be in hierarchy order of top-level-manager > mid-level-manager > employee.

Comment: @MT0: yes. OP showed a hierarchy with just 2 levels and did not mention that more could exist, so the query does not mean to handle more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query to get the count at any depth of the hierarchy using `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` to get the reportees' managers at each level of the hierarchy. This only requires a single table-scan (unlike queries using `UNION`).

```sql
SELECT "USER",
       COUNT( * ) AS issue_count
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( mgr ) AS mgr,
         emp
  FROM   tblEmp
  CONNECT BY PRIOR emp = mgr
)
UNPIVOT ( "USER" FOR value IN ( emp, mgr ) )
GROUP BY "USER"
```

**Output**:

> ```
> USER | ISSUE_COUNT
> :--- | ----------:
> ijk  |           1
> kkk  |           2
> lll  |           2
> abc  |           3
> xyz  |           4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a030e73016367552ed9ab97faf35e64b)*

---

**Update**:

If you want it to be ordered by the hierarchy then it gets a lot more complicated:

```sql
WITH issues_with_top_level_managers ( emp, issue_no, mgr ) AS (
  SELECT emp, issue_no, mgr
  FROM   tblEmp
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT mgr, NULL, NULL
    FROM   tblEmp
    MINUS
    SELECT emp, NULL, NULL
    FROM   tblEmp
  )
),
grouped_issues ( emp, issue_count, mgr ) AS (
  SELECT emp,
         COUNT( issue_no ) AS issue_count,
         mgr
  FROM   issues_with_top_level_managers
  GROUP BY emp, mgr
)
SELECT emp,
       ( SELECT SUM( issue_count )
         FROM   grouped_issues c
         START WITH c.emp = gi.emp
         CONNECT BY PRIOR emp = mgr ) AS issue_count
FROM   grouped_issues gi
START WITH mgr IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR emp = mgr
ORDER SIBLINGS BY emp
```

**Output**:

> ```
> EMP | ISSUE_COUNT
> :-- | ----------:
> lll |           2
> kkk |           2
> xyz |           4
> abc |           3
> ijk |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d1526118281a2aa9de86bf371f64b599)*

Comment: Output is not as expected. query should order reportees after their manager with a bit indentation like as follows:

user  issue_count
-----------------
xyz        4
  abc     3  
  ijk       1
lll     2
  kkk     2


abc and ijk has manager xyz so they should be shown after xyz same like other.

Comment: @nam Updated with another hierarchical query that gets the order.

Comment: Thanks, could you help me with query if emp and manager details are in different table. in above query only emp and issue_counts are there and there is another table called emp_details having (emp, mgr). Could you please let me know how we can get above output in that case. That is the actuall requirement.

Comment: @nam Please don't do a bait-and-switch and change the context of your question in comments once you have got something that answers the question you originally asked. If you want an answer to a specific question then make sure your question reflects that or else ask a second follow up question. That said - you want something like this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9f04b58fab5a8e4504d2ae372974507e).