# SQL query needed for stats based on 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table1 like as follows:

```
create table table1
(
     empname varchar(10), 
     issue_no number
);

insert into table1(empname, issue_no) values('abc',123);
insert into table1(empname, issue_no) values('ijk',222);
insert into table1(empname, issue_no) values('abc',333);
insert into table1(empname, issue_no) values('abc',444);
insert into table1(empname, issue_no) values('kkk',555);
insert into table1(empname, issue_no) values('kkk',555);
```

Another table `emp_details` like

```
create table emp_details
(
     emp varchar2(10), 
     mgr varchar2(10)
);

insert into emp_details(emp) values('abc','xyz');
insert into emp_details(emp) values('ijk','xyz');
insert into emp_details(emp) values('kkk','lll');
```

I need a query which will return first manager row and count of issues under him/reportes and in later rows employee and count of their issues.

Table output should be like:

```
        user | issue_count
        -----+-----------
        xyz     4
        abc     3
        ijk     1
        lll     2
        kkk     2
```

Order of employe which don't have any reporte can be in any order. Please note indentation is also import to figure out manager and its reporte.

Comment: Someone asked a very similar question here just a couple of hours ago. See if you can find it. (Perhaps someone taking the same class?)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58214771/gets-stats-of-employee-and-manager-from-a-table

Comment: That seems in table. My problem is how to write query if we have 2 tables.

Comment: @SubhashTiwari . . . This requires a recursive CTE or hierarchical query.  What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please. You need two group by, simple and faster way  through union

```
SELECT a.mgr, count(b.issue_no), min(b.issue_no) rn, 1 ord
 FROM emp_details a, table1 b 
    where a.emp = b.emp (+)
group by a.mgr
UNION ALL
SELECT b.emp, count(*), min(b.issue_no)rn, 2 ord
 FROM  table1 b
GROUP BY  b.emp 
order by rn, ord
```

OUTPUT:

```
xyz 4   123 1
abc 3   123 2
ijk 1   222 2
lll 2   555 1
kkk 2   555 2
```

Comment: Above query is not giving correct output:

MGR COUNT(*)
xyz 1
lll 2
ijk 1
abc 3
kkk 2

xyz should have 4 also the order they are displaying is not expected. reportees should be displayed under manager.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea should be constructing a hierarchical query which could be done by using such a `union all` clause in the first step(subquery) and depending on the logic that *every manager is an employee at the same time*, and in the second query the logic of ordering is prepared by `dense_rank()` analytical function :

```
with e1 as
(
 select emp, mgr from
 (
  select distinct mgr as emp, null as mgr
    from emp_details
  union all  
  select emp, mgr
    from emp_details
  )
 connect by prior emp = mgr
), e2 as
(
select e.*, dense_rank() over (order by e.mgr desc) as dr, t.cnt 
  from e1 e left join (select emp, count(*) as cnt from table1 group by emp) t on t.emp=e.emp 
), e3 as
(
select 0 as emp_group, mgr as "user", count(*) as "issue count", max(dr) as dr
  from e2 group by mgr 
 union all  
select 1 as emp_group, emp, max(cnt), max(dr) from e2 group by emp
)
select "user", "issue count"
  from e3
 where "issue count" is not null and "user" is not null
 order by dr, emp_group;

user    issue count
-----   -----------
xyz      4
ijk      1
abc      3
lll      2
kkk      2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c5bf601df82c6842fdd293b7d3beddf1)</kbd>

Comment: Hi,

Order by is an issue here. ijk comes under manager xyz so it should be shown under xyz before or after abc.

Comment: I am bit confuse in understanding this query due to same column name emp.
I have renamed first column name as empname in table1.
Could you please help me in understanding the query now?

Comment: you know we're joining tables through emp columns ( one of them is empname currently. Btw, I'd prefer using numeric values e.g. IDs ). And we know that every manager is an employee, and managers has no manager administering them in your case. So I started the queries by applying union all among ordinary empolyee with their managers at the same rows and managers aliased as employee with null managers @SubhashTiwari .